# Native Force.com Rest App Template is not showing in New Project Wizard

Tags: iphone, salesforce, force.com

I followed this link http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Mobile_SDK_for_iOS#Working_with_the_SDK

to as to integrate my iOS App with the SalesForce. Now while creating new project I can't se the Native Force.com Rest App Template in New Project Wizard, instead only Hybrid Force.com App template is been shown.

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently solved this problem by Updating to OS X 10.7.3 and doing a fresh install of XCode 4.3.1, then re-installing SalesForce. After the re-install, the REST template was right where it belonged!

Make sure you set the XCode directory so that SF knows where to put the files, otherwise the install will hang!

```
    sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

I hope you get it solved!

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Mobile SDK for iOS was updated to version 1.1 this past week. Among the fixes were updated instructions for installing the SDK on Xcode 4.3. The old install script doesn't work for the latest version of Xcode so getting the latest source code from [Github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS) might solve your problem.